# Get Variables from Checkbox in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I tried to create a multiple checkboxes and get the information whether they are checked or not. I tried to use tkinter for this purpose. The number of checkboxes would be variable. Up to now, I found a way to create the checkboxes with the following code. With this, 10 checkboxes are created at which people can tick any of them

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=20, 
                            yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        n=10
        for i in range(n):
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Modul %s" % i)
            self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            self.text.insert("end", "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, the information are not saved in any variable. If I add variable to be dumped in the cb, the code will check every checkboxes. The edited code section is as follow (sorry that I couldn't highlight the addition):

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=20, 
                            yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        n=10
        var1 = IntVar()
        val =[]
        for i in range(n):
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Modul %s" % i, variable=var1)
            self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
            self.text.insert("end", "\n") # to force one checkbox per line
            val.append(var1.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Could you help what can I add to the code in order to be able to get the checked Modules by the user? for instance I will get in "val" variable a list with [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] if somebody tick module 0, 2, and 6

I look forward for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```py
import tkinter as tk

def done():
    result = []
    for var in variables:
        result.append(var.get())
    print(result)

root = tk.Tk()

variables = []
check_buttons = []
for i in range(10):
    var = tk.IntVar(root)
    check_button = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Modul %i" % i, variable=var)
    check_button.pack()

    variables.append(var)
    check_buttons.append(check_button)

done_button = tk.Button(root, text="Done", command=done)
done_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I created 10 variables in a list called `variables` and connected them to each `Checkbutton`

Comment: Thanks. need to add the mainloop in the code

Comment: @Fadri Forgot the `mainloop` :D. I edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple, the mistake is you are creating one `IntVar` for all the checkbuttons, what you should be having is different `IntVar` for different buttons. Then what I want to add is, instead of `val` being the values from `IntVar` let it be the `IntVar` themselves, so later it can be reused. Here I am using `bind` to print the list, you can create a button and add `command` option to it.

```
self.val = [] # self.val if you want to access it outside __init__, or just val
for i in range(n):
    var1 = IntVar()
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Modul %s" % i, variable=var1)
    self.text.window_create("end", window=cb)
    self.text.insert("end", "\n") # to force one checkbox per line
    self.val.append(var1)
self.text.bind('<Return>',lambda e:print([x.get() for x in self.val])) # Dummy function to just print a new list
```

What is `[x.get() for x in self.val]` ? It is simple List Comprehension which means:

```
temp = [] # Any empty list
for x in self.val:
    temp.append(x.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing (tho probably other answers will better suit You depending on what You know):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, IntVar
from functools import partial


def func(n):
    print(f'Selected {n + 1}') if variables[n].get() == 1 else print(f'Deselected {n + 1}')


variables = []

root = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    variables.append(IntVar())
    Checkbutton(root, text=f'Option {i + 1}', variable=variables[i], command=partial(func, i)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

(By suggestion @CoolCloud You can replace the shown command with this: `command=lambda i=i: func(i)`, that should also work, also then You don't have to import functools)

However this is a pretty compact setup.

Explanation:

First there is an empty list, where all the Checkbox variables will be stored.

Then in range 10 which means that 10 Checkboxes will be created we do the following:

1. First we append a variable to the list that will get assigned to each Checkbutton
2. Then it creates a Checkbutton and adds to it the variable by using indexing and immediately packs it.

About that command:

The partial basically makes it so that the function given in its argument will always get executed with that variable. More about that [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/partial-functions-in-python)

`func()` function:

print number of option when selected, otherwise print the number when deselected (adding the correct 'selected: no' and 'deselected: no'). It can also be written as:

```py
if all_checkboxes[n][0].get() == 1:
    print(f'Selected {n + 1}')
else:
    print(f'Deselected {n + 1}')
```

Hope this helps, if You have any questions ask them.

> Source for information about [Checkbox](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm) and its attributes and arguments.

Comment: Why does your 'You' always begin with capital?

Comment: @CoolCloud because it shows respect, doesn't it?(so it is from an ethical standpoint) Also I just understood how partial works and that allowed me to reduce my code even more.

Comment: `lambda i=i` does the same thing `partial` does over here but ok. No it does not look respectful, but if you feel so, then fine.

Comment: @CoolCloud well thanks for that information, didn't know that (about lambda). About  'You' well I thought it was the formal, the one one would use to write a formal letter, version of 'you' (since in my language similarly it would be) so that is why I used it. And it still feels like that would be the proper way to talk to people I don't know (even tho I also use it in everyday chatting with my friends (the formal of 'you' in my language))